# API Redcap : Using date filtrer

Tags: redcap

I would like to know if it's possible to create a filter regarding dates.
For example, I would like to have the state of the database at a specific date. So, any modifications to the data that occurred afterward should not be taken into account.
Currently, I've tried using dateRangeEnd, but it keeps the individuals that were included before that date. However, if any of their information has been modified after my date, I'll get the modified value instead of the original value.

Thank you.

Comment: What program are you using to call the REDCap API? And what API method (e.g., exporting records, exporting metadata, export reports, etc.)? When exporting records, the API always returns the most recent version of the data, so you'll always get the modified value instead of the original value. If you want the original value, you'll need to export the *logs* instead and filter based on the type of action (e.g., "Update record" if the data has been modified multiple times or "Create record" if you want the original data). You can pass a log end date to filter your result as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I use the Stata software with the following function with shell function

So i can add dateRangeEnd but it  doesnt work as i want

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying! I'm not familiar with Stata, as my primary programming language is R, so though the syntax will differ, the process will likely be very similar. You can request the logs instead of records using the REDCap API by changing the raw parameter `content` to `content=log` instead of `content=record`. This opens up new parameters for `logtype` (all events except page views, data exports, manage/design, record created-updated-deleted, page views, etc.), `beginTime`, and `endTime`. Those last two function quite similar to the `dateRangeEnd` parameter because they allow you to filter the log using date-times (has to be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format). The response returns `action` and `details` keys which contain your data of interest (e.g., the state of a given record at a given time). `Action`s relevant to you would probably be record creation, record updates, and record deletion. `details` contain the former and new values and you can perform additional data manipulation as you see fit. So in R, it might look something like this:

```
token <- "my_api_token"
url <- "my_redcap_uri"
formData <- list("token"=token,
    content='log',    # query the logs rather than current records
    logtype='record', # filter to record create-update-delete only
    user='',          # if blank, this means all users
    record='',        # if blank, this means all records
    beginTime='2023-03-31 09:39',
    endTime='',
    format='json',
    returnFormat='json'
)
response <- httr::POST(url, body = formData, encode = "form")
result <- httr::content(response)
head(result)
```

Which then might print out something like the following (example modeled off of [REDCapR package](https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/)):

```
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   timestamp           username        action            details           record
#>   <dttm>              <chr>           <chr>             <chr>             <chr> 
#> 1 2023-03-31 09:39:00 john_doe Update Response 004 my_variable = … 004    
#> 2 2023-03-31 09:49:35 john_doe Update Response 004 my_other_varia… 004    
#> 3 2023-03-31 10:25:14 john_doe Update Response 005 my_other_varia… 005    
#> 4 2023-03-31 11:12:56 john_doe Create Record 006   first_name = A… 006    
#> 5 2023-03-31 11:39:47 john_doe Update Response 006 my_variable = … 006    
#> 6 2023-03-31 12:49:33 john_doe Update Response 006 my_other_varia… 006
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think this is exactly what I wanted. I would like to have the records but have the database as it was at a specific date. For example, if an individual is a man on 02/10 and we change their gender after this date, I would like to import the data as of 02/10 and have the information as "man" and not the modified value.

Comment: A REDCap administrator might be able to download the database as it was at a specific date, but as a normal REDCap user, this is the only way I can think of to programmatically access previous data states. So if record 004's `gender` = `male` before 02/10, you would pass your timestamp filter to the API and then use some string detection methods to pull the data you need out of the `details` column. You can also pass specific records as a parameter to the API so that the result is the data history of a single record of interest.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i get the original value of the variable ? For non dummies variables. For exemple if we have the category "don't want to answer" as 98 in the variable gender. The log says "gender ='0'" but i don't know if it was 1 or 98 before . My problem is that we have many instruments and visits so the log are not really acurate

Comment: By original value, I assume you mean the first time the variable had any value entered at all. In that case, you would filter by action type = "Create record" for your record(s) of interest and the `details` item would contain the original value. Since I don't work in Stata, I'm not sure how it parses JSON responses (the format returned by the API) so your data may not be tabular as shown in my example above since I use R. REDCap keeps a log of *all* data changes since the beginning of the project so the logs are always accurate, albeit messy, especially if values change frequently over time.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try something with that. 
Do you know if we can split the log by instruments? Because i have some variable with same names in two differents instruments

Comment: From reading the REDCap API documentation, it doesn't look like you can filter the log by instrument. Your variables might share the same *variable label*, which is usually the human-readable name (e.g., you may have two instruments, each with a "Visit Date" variable) shown on forms and survey, but the log always returns the *raw variable name* which is the behind-the-scenes name that is machine-readable and is *always* unique (e.g., "Visit Date" could be `enrollment_visit_date` in one instrument and `follow_up_visit_date` in another). Consult your project's codebook.

Comment: Thanks again. Finally, the problem wasn't with the instruments but with the different visits. We have several visits that are under the same instrument (visit with M1 M2 M3). When I directly look at the logs, it clearly states in actions "Update record Patient_x (Visit M02)" but when I use the API, it only says "Update record Patient_x", so I can't determine which visit the variable refers to.